# Python DataFrame displaying zeros instead of calculated values from numpy zeros command

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am trying to make a DataFrame in python and update the various rows and columns in the dataframe though a loop based on various calculations.  The calculations are all correct, but when I try to display the DataFrame once the loop is complete, some of the numbers calculated are displayed yet I also see mostly zeros.  Below is an example code:

```
map = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros([16, 6]), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])
for i in range(0, len(map)):
    map.A[i] = 1+1     #Some calculations
    map.B[i] = map.A[i] + 2
print map
```

Result (just an example):

```
     A     B     C     D     E     F
1    2     4     0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
2    0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
3    0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
4    0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
5    0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
(continues for 16 rows)
```

However, if I were to print a specific clolumn, I would get the real calculated numbers.  Also, calcB uses the correct numbers from calcA so it has to be just a print error.  I am guessing it is something to do with initializing the array and the memory but I am not sure.  I originally used np.empty([16, 6]) but the same result occured.  How do I get the DataFrame to print the actual numbers, not the zeros?

Comment: Works for me.  When I run your code, column `A` is all 2, and column `B` is all 4.

Comment: Works for me, too. Just re-execute and see.

Comment: I also can't reproduce your output. By the way, it's not a good idea to name your variable `map`, since this shadows the built in `map()` function

Comment: I tried to run through the code and still had the same results.  Is there a more efficient way to do calculations and insert them into a dataframe with predefined column names?

The variable map is not actually something I use, I just changed the variable names from my actual code!  Thanks for the advice though.